# 401 Error trying to run solrConfigureTaks after changes to MyIndex.php

Tags: solr, silverstripe

I have a stage server that until yesterday had a working Solr search using [silverstripe-solr-search module](https://github.com/Firesphere/silverstripe-solr-search)

Then I tried to add Files to the search by adding a Search/MyIndex.php to the app code, referencing it in mysite.yml like this:

```
Firesphere\SolrSearch\Indexes\BaseIndex:
  class: MyIndex
```

Now running

```
vendor/bin/sake dev/tasks/SolrConfigureTask flush=all
```

Or

```
vendor/bin/sake dev/tasks/SolrIndexTask
```

Or just using the search, gives me an error:

```
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/logging?since=0&wt=json` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
```

Removing the changes does not get rid of the error.

I've checked that solr is running

```
service solr status
● solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-07-21 14:46:03 UTC; 16min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1493118 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 21 14:45:50 site-stage systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service...
Jul 21 14:45:50 site-stage su[1493125]: (to solr) root on none
Jul 21 14:45:50 site-stage su[1493125]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user solr by (uid=0)
Jul 21 14:46:03 site-stage systemd[1]: Started LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
```

I have configured the module in search.yml:

```
---
Name: MySolrSearch
After: SolrSearch

---
Firesphere\SolrSearch\Services\SolrCoreService:
  config:
    endpoint:
      localhost:
        host: localhost
        port: 8983
        timeout: 10
        # set up timeouts
        index_timeout: 10
        optimize_timeout: 100
        finalize_timeout: 300
        http_method: 'AUTO'
        # commit within 60ms
        commit_within: 60
  store:
    mode: 'file'
    path: '/var/solr/data'
  cpucores: 2
```

and set SOLR_PASSWORD and SS_SOLR_INDEX in the .env file

Looking at the docs, i tried to reapply the permissions suggested here:
https://firesphere.github.io/solr-docs/15-Help/03-Known-issues.html#solr-and-permission-issues

```
sermod -a -G www-data solr
groups solr
usermod -a -G solr www-data
groups www-data
chown -R solr:www-data /var/solr
chmod -R u+rwxs,g+rwxs /var/solr
```

which has not fixed it.

How can I fix my solr search?

Comment: I dont know how it used to work, but SOLR_PASSWORD didnt seem to do anything. I had to add the password and user to the search.yml as per the docs.  Its an old site with previous developers, so not sure what the history is there

Comment: The error message seems truncated, isn't the 401 more verbose, ie. mentioning "bad credentials" or anything else ? Did you try to set both `username` and `password` under `localhost` in search.yml ? If you changed anything in the solr config itself, then you probably need to restart Solr.

Comment: Hi @EricLavault - thats all it gave me.  agree its unhelpful